# Sanitize column names for Bold and Identity with xtable in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

Is there a way to pass xtable's identity function to sanitize the column names AND another custom function to bold the column names? There are two code chunks below, one to set up the dummy function and then another to print the xtable. It fails on the $ symbol in the first column name and the $ symbol in the table value is properly sanitized.

Thanks!

```
<<setup>>=
library(knitr)
library(xtable)
two_functions = function(x){
  paste("\\textbf{", x, "}", sep = "")
  # use xtable's 'identity' function to convert special characters
}

options(xtable.sanitize.colnames.function = two_functions)
@

<<xtable, results='asis'>>=
xtab = data.frame(a = c("Horse and $buddy", "Paddy Wagon", "Hospital Care", "Peanut butter and toast", "Cheese Whiz with Mayo"),
                  b = c(10000000, 200000.4533, 3098765435.65456, 408765467.654456, 50.00000))
colnames(xtab) = c("Hello money $ bag$", "Numbers")
print(xtable(xtab))
@
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on the error you are running into?  How are you knitting the document, via a button in RStudio? Explicitly from the console? When I run the code I do not run into any errors and the result is as expected.

Comment: @Peter That code does not provide an error, but the $ symbols in the column headers do not show up for me. It puts the Latex table column header into math mode. I would like a function to run both the default 'identity' sanitize function on column headers as well as make the column headers bold. Hope that clarifies...?

Comment: @Peter And to answer the previous questions (sorry) I am knitting with knitr, pdflatex, using the compile button on RStudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution maybe as simple as using `gsub` within the `two_functions` call.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<<setup>>=
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

two_functions = function(x){
    gsub("\\$", "\\\\$", paste("\\textbf{", x, "}", sep = ""))
}

options(xtable.sanitize.colnames.function = two_functions,
        xtable.sanitize.rownames.function = NULL,
        xtable.sanitize.text.function     = NULL)

@

<<xtable, results='asis'>>=
xtab = data.frame(a = c("Horse and $buddy", "Paddy Wagon", "Hospital Care", "Peanut butter and toast", "Cheese Whiz with Mayo"),
                  b = c(10000000, 200000.4533, 3098765435.65456, 408765467.654456, 50.00000))
colnames(xtab) = c("Hello money $ bag$", "Numbers")
print(xtable(xtab))
@
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit

To use the default `xtable` function for sanitizing a string replace the `two_functions` function above with the following:

```
two_functions = function(x){
  paste0("\\textbf{", xtable::sanitize(x, type = "latex"), "}")
}
```

Here the `xtable::sanitize` function is called first and then the resulting stings are placed inside of the LaTeX `\textbf{}` environment.

The resulting table is:

[image]

Comment: @ Peter Nice avatar by the way. Yes I agree that is a working function to replace the $ symbols, but the default sanitize function covers more symbols than just the $ character. So the ideal function would combine both the sanitize (including more than just the $ character) function and bold functions.

Comment: @Prevost, I've edited my answer.  Using `xtable::sanatize` within the `two_functions` call should do the trick.

Comment: I think that's it! I will try it out when I'm back with my computer and then if it works for me I will mark your answer correct. Thanks again....